# Kial "el de" kaj ne "el" nur?

Tags: prepositions

> La transdono **el de** unu generacio al la sekva estas la renoviga
> procezo de la lingvo... (Lindstedt, J. Lingvo - rimedo aŭ resurso?, p52)

Kial la aŭtoro ne simple skribis: "La transdono **el** unu generacio al la sekva estas la renoviga procezo de la lingvo..."?

Comment: Ŝajnas ke _el de_ volas esprimi _de io el:_, aŭ _de ... al_.  Tamen estas dubinda lingvouzo. Mi konsentas kun vi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gramatike, `el de` ĝi *povus* esti akceptebla, same kiel `el sub`, `el malantaŭ`, [kaj tiel plu](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/el.html#i-d16), por montri originon de movo.

Tamen, `el` jam enkondukas [devenon, originon aŭ fonton](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/el.html#i-3ds) do ne bezonatas aldoni `de`. Mi opinias tiun `de` superflua, sed sentas ĝin erara.

Aldone, sed ne nepre (mal)pravige estas neniu trafo por `el de` [en Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=63d3d08e744ee).